# What are the FPS of the FaceTime Camera for the iPhone 6S vs 7+ vs X vs iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, camera

We are capturing video from iOS devices and processing it using OpenGL but are encountering a FPS difference between the devices when trying to set them at their maximum rate.

The iPhone 6S and iPad Pro FaceTime cameras are maxing at 60 fps.

The 7+ and iPhone X however are maxing at 30 fps.

It seems unusual that the FPS would decrease with later versions of Apple's hardware. We are trying to figure out if this is a software issue or simply the technical specifications for the frame rate for the FaceTime camera.

We looked on Apple's technical specifications page but the frame rates of the FaceTime cameras aren't listed (though the rear cameras are.) For example:
https://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/specs/
https://www.apple.com/iphone-x/specs/

What are the FPS of the FaceTime Camera for the iPhone 6S vs 7+ vs X vs iPad Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re correct. According to Apple’s [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH107-SW21)...

- iPhone 6s series front camera does up to 60 FPS (all formats)
- iPhone 7 series front camera does up to 30 FPS
- iPhone 8 series / X front camera does up to 60 FPS, but only in binned formats (so you probably need to set the device’s `activeFormat`, not just choose a preset)

iPad Pro info is also in the tables at that link.